# Architecture/Design - Where to store app configuration?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture

I am building a web app in Laravel.
I have many app configuration options, such as:

- prices of paid plans
- maximum days on trial mode
- maximum number of points a free user can have
- default email sender address

These options are used thoughout the app and should be available most of the time. I'm thinking on having a 'config' database table to store and a config object to access the data... Would that be a good solution? If not, how else should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generally two possibilities for such configuration:

- app/config http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration
- config tables in DB

Which one works better for your case depends on:

- How often does the configuration change?

Almost never, then go for files.
Quite often, then go for DB

- Who should be able to change the config?

Only your admin with cli/ssh access, then go for files.
A big group of people, then go for DB

- Does the config change per server?

If yes, then maybe you can leverage the environment detection methods from Laravels standard Config

- Simple values (files is enough) or complex "models" (DB)

Generally I would estimate flat files are always more performant and easily scalable.

---

In my current application I use both:

The flat file configs contain: File limits a user can upload; default thumbnail size; available languages; some 3rd-party tokens; mail return addresses.

I estimate that these things will only be changed once in a while and always need my (admin) intervention either way.

The DB has tables for package prices; award conditions and associated rewards.

These values the website owner (my client) can easily change himself and they also contain structured metadata. E.g. how to present an award, how it is called and translated etc.